# TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Tags: python, byte

## Edit:

I made the very trivial mistake of having bound `bytes` to something else previous to executing the following code. This question is now entirely trivial and probably doesn't help anyone. Sorry.

## Original question:

Code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
b = bytes([10, 20, 30, 40])
print(b)
```

Output:

```
3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-21fec5626bc3> in <module>()
      1 import sys
      2 print(sys.version)
----> 3 b = bytes([10, 20, 30, 40])
      4 print(b)

TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Documentation:

```
Type:        bytes
String form: b'hello world'
Length:      11
Docstring:
bytes(iterable_of_ints) -> bytes
bytes(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytes
bytes(bytes_or_buffer) -> immutable copy of bytes_or_buffer
bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes
bytes() -> empty bytes object

Construct an immutable array of bytes from:
  - an iterable yielding integers in range(256)
  - a text string encoded using the specified encoding
  - any object implementing the buffer API.
  - an integer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This helped me.  I did the same thing.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have assigned *a `bytes` value* to the name `bytes`:

```
>>> bytes([10, 20, 30, 40])
b'\n\x14\x1e('
>>> bytes = bytes([10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> bytes([10, 20, 30, 40])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

`bytes` is now bound to the value `b'\n\x14\x1e('`, which is not callable. This global is shadowing the built-in. Delete it:

```
del bytes
```

to reveal the built-in again.

Comment: Oh wow that's the stupidest thing I've done. Please down-vote me some more.

Comment: @Ray In 1999, someone at Lockheed Martin crashed a $125M spacecraft into Mars because they used imperial units instead of metric ones.  Don't feel too bad about this!